# How to update UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uikit

I have a UILabel that I would like to update. It has been added to the class by ctrl-cicking and adding through the XIB file. Im trying to update the label text after waiting for a short delay. As of now, there is nothing else going on except for the code below. Howver when I run this, the simulator blanks out for a moment and takes me straight to the last updated text. It doesnt show me the `100` just the `200`.

How do I get the label to update like I want it to. Ultimately Im trying to have a timer of sorts decrement inside the label.

Label linked from the XIB to header file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeRemainingLabel;
```

In Implmentation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.timeRemainingLabel.text = @"100";
    sleep(1);
    self.timeRemainingLabel.text = @"200";    
}
```

- It has been synthesized.
- XCode 4.3.2, Mac OSX 10.7.3, iOS Simulator 5.1 (running iPad), iOS 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that the execution sequence does not leave the method while in the `sleep`. This is the problem, because the UI subsystem never gets a chance to update the label to the `"100"` value before it gets a command to set it to `"200"`.

To do this correctly, first you need to create a timer in your init method, like this:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

Then you need to write the code for your `updateLabel` method:

```
-(void) updateLabel {
    NSInteger next = [timeRemainingLabel.text integerValue]-1;
    timeRemainingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", next];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That seemed to do it.

Answer (score 3):

It will never show you 100 like this because you are using `sleep` here which is stopping the execution of your program and just after 1 sec of `sleep` you are updating the text. If you want to do this then you can use an `NSTimer` for this.

Change your above code like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.timeRemainingLabel.text = @"100";

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

- (void) updateLabel
{
    self.timeRemainingLabel.text = @"200"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Your view doesn't appear till the view hasn't loaded and the text of the label `timeRemainingLabel` is `@"200"` when that happens. So you do not see the text changing. Use an `NSTimer` to do this instead and assign the text to the label in the selector:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInSeconds target:self selector:@selector(updateText) userInfo:nil repeats: YES/NO];
```

and in your update method, set the latest text as per your requirement:

```
-(void) updateText {
    self.timeRemainingLabel.text = latestTextForLabel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it now :)